# Looking for negative reference to women in the Avatamsaka Sutra

Tags: mahayana, reference-request, nichiren, avatamsaka-suttra

I came across this rather gender progressive comment from Nichiren

> If we examine the Flower Garland Sutra, the first sutra to be preached
>   after the Buddha attained enlightenment, we find that it is a Mahayana
>   work preached by the Buddha in his aspect as the Thus Come One of the
>   reward body. Thus, to the voice-hearers, cause-awakened ones, and
>   others, it was like daytime to an owl or nighttime to a hawk; though
>   they listened to it, it was as though they did so with deaf ears or
>   blind eyes. **This being the case, though people hoped that the sutra
>   would enable them to pay back the four debts of gratitude, because it
>   speaks disparagingly of women,3 it was hardly possible for them to
>   repay the debt of gratitude owed to their mothers with the sutra.**

which is footnoted with

> 3) For example, the Daishonin cites the passage “Women are messengers of
>   hell who can destroy the seeds of Buddhahood. They may look like
>   bodhisattvas, but at heart they are like yaksha demons” with regard to
>   the Flower Garland Sutra. This passage is cited in A Collection of
>   Treasures as a quotation from the Flower Garland Sutra.

http://www.nichirenlibrary.org/en/wnd-2/Content/264

I can't for the life of me find this or anything like it in my [Cleary edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0877739404) of the Avatamsaka. (I believe it is there, I've read all sorts of misogynistic passages in sutras, I just can't find it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded [the Chinese translation of the Avataṃsaka Sūtra](http://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E6%96%B9%E5%BB%A3%E4%BD%9B%E8%8F%AF%E5%9A%B4%E7%B6%93%E5%85%AB%E5%8D%81%E5%8D%B7) and did a few searches for patterns with different combinations of words that are likely to appear there (e.g. 女 "woman", 地獄 "hell", 種 "seed", 夜叉 "Yaksha"). I found quite a few phrases, but none of them looked like the cited passage. My knowledge of classical Chinese is very rudimentary, so I may be mistaken. However, the search inside the Cleary translation on the Amazon website doesn't show any such passage either. So if it is there at all, I think it's more likely that the quote is a summary/paraphrase of a larger chunk of the sutra, and not a direct translation.

EDIT: I found a classical Chinese/classical Japanese phrase that is the source of your quote:

> 女人地獄使。能断仏種子。外面似菩薩。内心如夜叉。

It can be found in [this text](http://www.genshu.gr.jp/DPJ/database/bunken/goibun/f_tyu_b.htm) at 7-094. Unfortunately, there is no information about the author nor the date when it was written. In any case, it is definitely not modern Japanese, so I don't think it was written recently. It seems to be a Nichiren commentary to the Lotus Sutra.

EDIT 2: The above quote is preceded by "華厳経云", which means "Avataṃsaka Sūtra says". That explains why the passage is commonly (and incorrectly, as we may conclude) attributed to this sutra.

EDIT 3: I found [information about the origin of the quote](http://www.nichirenlibrary.org/en/wnd-1/Content/14), which, in light of the facts presented above, we can regard as conclusive:

> This statement is not found in the extant Chinese versions of the Flower Garland Sutra. However, A Collection of Treasures written by Taira no Yasuyori during the Jisho era (1177–1181) cites it as a quotation from the Flower Garland Sutra.

Comment: cool, I re-googled it and hit on 2nd theory of the actual source of the quote.

Comment: Nice! And based on your answer I managed to find what looks like the original Classical Chinese/Classical Japanese quote.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the actual source.

In an anthology of [Japanese Literature, I find almost the exact same text](https://books.google.com/books?id=9xytAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA542&ots=aHaLBMPyKn&dq=Women%20are%20messengers%20of%20hell&pg=PA542#v=onepage&q=Women%20are%20messengers%20of%20hell&f=false), in what looks like a modern fictionalized discussion between two monks, one who says the quote is from Vasubandhu's "The Treatise on Consciousness-Only" I haven't confirmed that, because I can't find the full text of it.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, "The Treatise on Consciousness-Only" was not written by Vasubandhu, but it's Xuanzang's commentary to his works. Again, I grepped through the Chinese original (http://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E6%88%90%E5%94%AF%E8%AD%98%E8%AB%96), but didn't find anything that looks like the quote.

Answer (score 0):

The concluding chapter of the Avatamsaka is the Gandavyuha, widely regarded as a sutra in it's own right. The Gandavyuha honours women more than any other sutra that I know of. It tells how a pilgrim named Sudhana discovers a succession of teachers, including 22 who are female. Each of the 22 female teachers gives Sudhana a vitally important insight into the true nature of reality, including the  Indra's Net principle of interconnection and inter-reflection.