# Identification of a Buddhist text written in classical Chinese or Japanese

Tags: reference-request, sutras, chinese-buddhism, nichiren, chinese-canon

While looking for an answer to [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/looking-for-negative-reference-to-women-in-the-avatamsaka-sutra) I found [a text that contains the quote in question](http://www.genshu.gr.jp/DPJ/database/bunken/goibun/f_tyu_b.htm), but I cannot find any information about it.

- Is it written in classical Chinese or classical Japanese? (The two written languages were apparently quite similar)
- Is it a commentary to the Lotus Sutra as the title seems to indicate?
- When was it written and by whom?
- Are the divisions equivalent to the divisions of the Lotus Sutra?
- Do the line numbers also point to the lines of the sutra?

Comment: I have no idea what this text is but I can tell that it is in Chinese, not Japanese, because if it were Japanese it would have kana in it instead of just Hanzi.

Comment: It's not that clear. For example, in the title the Japanese character 経 is used instead of one of the Chinese variants:經 or 经. Moreover, in it's earliest form, classical Japanese was written only with Chinese characters.

Comment: Seems like it was a commentary/notes by Nichiren when he studied the Lotus Sutra (http://www.genshu.gr.jp/DPJ/database/bunken/goibun/ibun_tyu.htm)

Answer (score 3):

1. It is classical Chinese written in part of Chinese character and part of Japanese kanji Character,  it is still Chinese text, I can identify it because I am a Chinese speaker.
2. Yes it is Lotus Sutra
3. Kumārajīva and Yao Qin translated an ancient book "龜茲文本" to Chinese, that is Lotus Sutra

I can only answer this, I have no information for the rest of questions

Comment: Lotus Sustra came out at 406 A.D